# Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime - how to make listbox longer length when selecting

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

Simplified xaml to demonstrate my problem, the listbox.item's are added in the code behind (but not relevant to the question):

```
<Grid Height="200">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox x:Name="lbPurpose"  FontSize="28" />
</Grid>
```

When the listbox is tapped, it is only 1 row high (60 pixels as set by the row definition). Is there a property that can be set to allow it to grow to 200 pixels when in focus to make scrolling through the list easier - but return to original size when not in focus? It's very dificult to scroll through when only one row is displayed at a time.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use a storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Rookie mistake.......... I actually wanted a combo box and the Grid row height should have been auto. Thanks!!

```
<Grid Height="200">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox x:Name="lbPurpose"  FontSize="28"/>
<Grid>
```